# how to dispose of zero elements of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, null, element

I have the following matrix.

Mat

```
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.3421638 0.6578362 0.0000000 0.0000000
[2,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3417066 0.6582934
[3,] 0.6237054 0.3762946 0.0000000 0.0000000
[4,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3567124 0.6432876
```

I would like to extract the matrix without the null elements.

Mat

```
     0         1
[1,] 0.3421638 0.6578362
[2,] 0.3417066 0.6582934
[3,] 0.6237054 0.3762946
[4,] 0.3567124 0.6432876
```

How do I do that in code R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 t(apply(Mat, 1, function(x)x[x!=0]))
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.3421638 0.6578362
[2,] 0.3417066 0.6582934
[3,] 0.6237054 0.3762946
[4,] 0.3567124 0.6432876
```